# homework: Proving n <= 2^(n/4)?

Tags: math, complexity-theory, big-o

So I have an assignment question where I have to prove:

```
n^4 is in O(2^n)
```

Just by looking at the graphs of the functions I know that with c=1 and n[0] = 16 this is true.

While trying to prove it on paper I managed to reduce the inequality down to `n <= 2^(n/4)`, however, I cannot figure out how to simplify this further or adequately prove from here that with n[0]=16 the big-O assertion holds.

Any help?

Comment: take log  on both sides

Comment: Post on [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.


Comment: I disagree that this is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to prove that the inequality holds for n >= 16 using induction, no calculus required:

First, for n=16 you have 16<sup>4</sup>=2<sup>16</sup>.

If the inequality holds for n=k, for n=k+1 you have (k+1)<sup>4</sup> = (`####`)·k<sup>4</sup> < 2k<sup>4</sup> ≤ 2·2<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>k+1</sup>.

QED.

<sub>Since this is homework, I'll leave leave the crucial step, finding what goes in place of `####`, to the reader.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The title is incorrect, and the error is important.

You are not trying to prove that n ≤ 2<sup>n/4</sup>, you are trying to prove that n ∊ O(2<sup>n/4</sup>), which is a strictly weaker claim.  It is impossible to prove that n ≤ 2<sup>n/4</sup> because at n=2, the inequality is **false**.

By taking the logarithm of both sides, we can reduce the problem to that of showing that log n ∊ O(n), which is easy to show because d/dn log n ≤ 1 for n ≥ 1.